# On worker 2: UndefVarError

Tags: julia

I am trying a simple Julia code:

```
using Distributed

addprocs(1)

@everywhere include("count_heads.jl")

a = @spawn count_heads(100000000)

b = @spawn count_heads(100000000)


fetch(a)+fetch(b)
```

However the count_heads.jl contains the following function:

```
function count_heads(n)
c::Int = 0
for i = 1:n
    c += rand(Bool)
   end
c
end
```

But the above code was showing the error :
*On worker 2:
UndefVarError: count_heads not defined*

Does anyone know how to resolve this error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@spawn` is deprecated and you  should use `@spawnat :any` instead:

```
a = @spawnat :any count_heads(100000000)
```

otherwise your code is perfectly correct and I managed to run it.

Most likely, in your production code you have some typo in the function name or you have run `@everywhere include("count_heads.jl")` before `addprocs`

Comment: It is still showing the same error.
I have used '@spawnat :any'  and also declared '@everywhere include("count_heads.jl")' after 'addprocs'.

Comment: I've run your code and it just works. It also looks correct to me (with comments above). What Julia version are you using (although this code looks perfectly fine for at least Julia 1.0)